# Computing the p-value using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test

Tags: probability-or-statistics

#### The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for the simplified data {1,2,3,4}:

```
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[{1, 2, 3, 4}, UniformDistribution[{0, 5}]]
```

> `0.989934`

#### The p-value calculated with the CDF of Kolmogorov:

```
cdfK[x_] := 1 - 2 Sum[(-1)^(k - 1) Exp[-2 k^2*x^2], {k, 1, ∞}];
1 - cdfK[0.2*Sqrt[5]]
```

> 0.988261

Why are the p-values not equal?